# Qt - export private classes

Tags: qt

I need to use private classes like `QQuickTextEdit` (marked as `Q_QUICK_PRIVATE_EXPORT`). I built Qt from sources with `-developer-build` flag, but this only exports classes marked as `Q_AUTOTEST_EXPORT` in addition to traditional classes.

Is there any way how to force Qt to export all classes?

Comment: Did you try to specify QT += quick-private in .pro file? You should be able to use Q_QUICK_PRIVATE_EXPORT classes then

Comment: demonplus: yes sure, it is not working, because classes are not exported from shared library - only header file will not help